# How does git show committed file?

Tags: git

I added some files in the directory and wanted to add them to git:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "add some file"
```

As I have set `.ignore` under this directory, I want to observe which files were really added to git. How to do that?

Comment: One visual option on windows would be to use [tortoisegit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/). It will add icons to the files showing their status.

Answer (score 2):

Do `git status` just after the `git add .`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
git log --name-status
```

to see which files are added/modified/deleted in each commit.

Comment: He wants to know which files are added, *before* doing the commit. `git log --name-status` show the files that are *already* commited.

Comment: I see. But since he said "I want to observe which files were really **added** to git. How to do that?" I did answer how to check which files were just **added**, once he does `git add .`, instead of which files were just **commited**. But probably the author meant the second thing, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `-v` (verbose) option to `git add`, it will list the files that got added by the operation:

```
» git add -v .
add 'hello1'
add 'hello2'
```

You can also use a visual tool to commit, like [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) on Windows, or the builtin [`git gui`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui). Both interfaces allow to see diffs of what changed in your working copy or your index, move files in and out from the index, and finally commit.